# Merge psql and postgresql tags

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

I do believe it is better to merge [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) and [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) tags, at least on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While questions related to [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) are always related to PostgreSQL, a lot of [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) questions don't relate to `psql` at all - there are other tools and APIs to access and manage PostgreSQL databases.

The tag wiki identifies what you should use [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) correctly for. I don't thing a merge or synonym is warranted here.

(For [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), you could ask the question on that [site-specific meta](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: always forgetting about site-specific meta, yep, this is more likely belong there. Will edit question and ask for migration